# Download CSV Data by looping over a Pandas Data frame which consists of 47 URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to develop a Python Script for my Data Engineering Project and I want to loop over 47 URLS stored in a dataframe, which downloads a CSV File and stores in my local machine. Below is the example of top 5 URLS:
[image]

```
test_url = "https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/pj7m-y5uh/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
req = requests.get(test_url)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('cdc6.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

I have this for a single file, but instead of the opening a CSV File and writing the Data in it, I want to directly download all the files and save it in local machine.

Comment: There are multiple ways to download data. You are at a research phase that is not suitable for stackoverflow. Once you have an implementation you can come with with specific problems in your code.

Comment: Alright! No problem, I will look into this as we speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate and then download the file to a folder. Iteration is easy by using the `.items()` method in pandas dataframes and passing it into a loop. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html).

Then, you want to download each item. Urllib has a `.urlretrieve(url, filename)` function for downloading a hosted file to a local file, which is elaborated on in the urllib documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).

Your code may look like:

```
for index, url in url_df.items():
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, "cdcData" + index + ".csv")
```

or if you want to preserve the original names:

```
for index, url in url_df.items():
    name = url.split("/")[-1]
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, name)
```

Comment: Invalid argument: 'rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD': So for each URL, the ending is in this Manner. Could you let me know if it could be downloaded to a particular path on my PC ?

Comment: That indicates that every file is named rows.csv, so you would want to use the first option. I believe that urlretrieve with a relative file path just puts the file into the same path as the python script (or notebook in your case). You can instead write to `"%HOMEPATH%\Documents\cdcData\cdcData" + index + ".csv"` or `"C:\User\ your username here \Documents..."` on Windows, or `"~/Documents/cdcData/cdcData" + index + ".csv"` on Ubuntu / Mac OS / other Unix based OS's.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm! I appreciate your help